# Audit.net - How to store Entity Framework audit event output to custom db table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, audit.net

I am trying to use Audit.Net as a part of an ASP.NET Core 5 Web API with EF to log both Web API calls and EF data changes.

As recommended in https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/issues/118#issuecomment-383443340 I specified EntityFrameworkProvider directly on my DB context so I can later use some other provider as global to log web api actions.

Each database table has an Audit table with additional columns like user id and event date. Each EF entity implements the `IAudit` interface so I can insert user and event time into entity audit tables.

I managed to get this part working, but I am not sure how to store Audit output containing contextId, transactionId, error message, transaction duration, maybe even `EntityFrameworkEvent` object as json. I wish to store this info in a separate custom table, and not in table of each EF entity audit table.

```
public partial class DbContext : AuditDbContext
{
     public static EntityFrameworkDataProvider AuditProvider = 
        new EntityFrameworkDataProvider(ef => ef.AuditTypeExplicitMapper(m => m
            .Map<SomeEntity, SomeEntityLog>()
            .Map<SomeEntity2, SomeEntityLog2>()
            .AuditEntityAction<IAudit>((evt, entry, auditEntity) =>
            {
                string username = evt.Environment.CustomFields["username"] as string;

                auditEntity.AuditDate = evt.StartDate;
                auditEntity.AuditUserName = username;
                auditEntity.AuditAction = entry.Action; 
                                                        
            })));

    public DbContext() 
    {
        this.AuditDataProvider = AuditProvider;
    }

    public DbContext(DbContextOptions<DbContext> options): base(options)
    {
        this.AuditDataProvider = AuditProvider;
    }
}
```

I did not manage to find an explanation in official documentation if this is possible to do, so I would appreciate some help.

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to do. do you want to store information into **two** different tables for each change?

Comment: In a way yes. I would like to have an Audit table per entity, but also a custom "Event" table to store EntityFrameworkEvent data. So on SaveChanges() a row would be added into each Audit table and one row into "Event" table containing information related to transaction performed.

Comment: I am trying to mimic behavior of Hibernate Envers where my audit consist of AuditEvent table containing event data, and one or more related EntityAudit tables containing information about entity changes.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find a solution. I added an override to `OnScopeSaving` in `DbContext` and there added a record into my AuditEvent table. Something like this:

```
public override void OnScopeSaving(IAuditScope auditScope)
{
     base.OnScopeSaving(auditScope);
    
     var evt = auditScope.Event;
    
     string username = evt.Environment.CustomFields["username"] as string;
    
     var efe = auditScope.GetEntityFrameworkEvent();
    
     this.AuditEvent.Add(new Models.AuditEvent
     {
         AuditUserName = username,
         ContextId = efe.ContextId,
         ErrorMessage = efe.ErrorMessage,
         Success = efe.Success,
         TransactionId = efe.TransactionId,
         EventDateUtc = evt.StartDate,
         Data = evt.ToJson(),
      });
}
```